# How to check if the time has reached the next or past day in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime

Given this sample data

```
var startDate = '2018-05-31';
var endDate = '2018-05-31';
var startTime = '17:30';
var endTime = '18:00';
```

I can only edit the `start time` and `end time`.
If user is trying to edit the end time, how to check if the time
has stepped on the next day which is not allowed, like e.g

```
start time = 17:30
end time = 23:59++ ?
```

Is there a way to prevent the start time and end time to show hours and minutes that is only allowed ?

Comment: if the hours > 23 it's next day, if hours < 0 it's previous day ... none of what you posted is in any way related to actual code, so ...

Comment: In JavaScript you have to use Date constructor. To do what you want you can use a package called Moment.JS.

Comment: You might want to consider paraphrasing your question because I don't understand at all. How is `23:59` considered the next day of `2018-05-31`?